# How to deploy Nextjs App on Google App engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

i am trying to deploy Nextjs app on Google App Engine but i am getting `500 server error` as show below [image]

i have deployed the app using the Google App Engine browser terminal..

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs12
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

above is the `app.yaml` code that i have used.
i have tried hosting React app with the above mentioned approach and it is hosting perfectly.
so, is there any way yo resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your issue with the exact error. The problem was with [`nodejs` version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/support-schedule#nodejs) compatibility. Try using `nodejs16` or above. This would solve your issue.

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs16
service: next-app

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Comment: i tried updating the node version to ```nodejs16``` but the problem still persists.. i am still getting the ```500 Server Error```.

Comment: hey, i solved it but thanks a lot to you too. Initially i saw the example on how to deploy React app on Google App Engine and thought the process would be same for the Next App also but i found out that i need to keep all the files in the directory along with ```build``` and ```app.yaml``` to host Next App.